# Ajax Post redirect to same url as posting data PHP

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, post

I want post data to "orders.php" and after a successful AJAX-response, it needs to redirect to orders.php again. When i try it like this, the response is lost. What do I need to do to make it work?

```
$('.orders').click(function(){

  var company_id_cart = '<?php echo $maincontent["company_id"]; ?>';       
  var cart_tel = '<?php echo $maincontent["tel"]; ?>';   

  $.ajax({
    url: 'orders.php',
    type: 'POST',
    data: {company_id_cart: company_id_cart, cart_tel: cart_tel},
    success: function(response){ 
      window.location.href = "orders.php";
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: That's how HTTP works - it's stateless. But if you're going to make an AJAX request to the same page you then redirect to, that's pretty pointless to be honest. Just post directly to orders.php without Ajax... that'll save one request and be more efficient

Comment: Random guess is that you need to add `event.preventDefault();` in your function; orders.php should be called and if that stores the response it should do so. Also, you might run into trouble with the way you encode your values, I would suggest you use: `var company_id_cart = <?php echo json_encode($maincontent["company_id"]); ?>;`, might save you some headache later (likewise for cart_tel).